# Login to website with HtmlUnit when login form is javascript

Tags: java, htmlunit

How can I login to  using HtmlUnit?

URL is: https://www.jambox.pl/ogladaj

The login form doesn't seem to have an ID so I can't get it by using `getFormByName()`.

Comment: Use jquery and use $(".form") and you'll get the forms object.

Comment: I want to log in to the site in Java

Comment: Wait, so you have a Java application that you want to use to call a javascript function with? I think you're out of luck then, short of creating a javascript runner and downloading the script... I think you'd have more luck downloading the script and studying it and creating your own version of it in Java. Make no mistake that Javascript and Java would be connected, Javascript is so called only because it shares some of its syntax with Java, not with its actual runtime or development.

Answer (score 1):

The form you are interested in is located inside an iframe. You have to dig a bit deeper...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.jambox.pl/ogladaj");

        HtmlInlineFrame frame = (HtmlInlineFrame) page.getElementById("jambox-frame");
        HtmlPage framePage = (HtmlPage) frame.getEnclosedPage();

        // the login elements
        framePage.getHtmlElementById("login-field").type("tester@jambox.pl");
        framePage.getHtmlElementById("password-field").type("victoria");

        for (HtmlForm form : framePage.getForms()) {
            if (form.getActionAttribute().equals("/widget2/")) {
                // System.out.println(form.asXml());
                for (HtmlElement input : form.getElementsByTagName("input")) {
                    if (input.getAttribute("value").startsWith("Zaloguj")) {
                        // System.out.println(input);
                        input.click();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an ID or name to get an `HtmlForm`

You can get all the forms of the page, and search for some specific attribute.

Or you can also use XPath directly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.jambox.pl/ogladaj");

        // get the form first
        for (HtmlForm form : page.getForms()) {
            System.out.println(form.asXml());
            //if this is your form, use it.
        }

        // or using XPath with attribute 'action'
        HtmlForm form2 = page.getFirstByXPath("//form[@action='/widget2']");
    }
}
```

However, it seems that HtmlUnit doesn't retrieve all the forms, which is a bug I think.

Answer (score 0):

I know how to get to the form.but Htmlpage not see the second form `<form action = "/ widget2 ">`

```
List<HtmlForm> list = new ArrayList<HtmlForm>();
list=page.getForms();
System.out.println(list.size());
HtmlForm form = list.get(0);
System.out.println(form.asXml());
```

this return code size

```
1

<form action="/ogladaj" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="search-theme-form">
  <div>
    <div id="search" class="container-inline">
      <div class="form-item" id="edit-search-theme-form-1-wrapper">
        <input type="text" maxlength="128" name="search_theme_form" id="edit-search-theme-form-1" size="15" value="Szukaj" class="form-text NormalTextBox txtSearch" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Szukaj') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Szukaj';}"/>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-submit" value="Szukaj" class="form-submit"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" id="form-Se_XpWDahQvAp1Wfd2dmZjjwvuAW37ojsRiy8RXlNHk" value="form-Se_XpWDahQvAp1Wfd2dmZjjwvuAW37ojsRiy8RXlNHk"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="form_id" id="edit-search-theme-form" value="search_theme_form"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```